# removing certain pattern from a string

Tags: r, vector, gsub, strsplit

I have a vector like below:

```
t <- c("8466 W Peoria Ave", "4250 W Anthem Way", .....)
```

I want to convert it into:

```
t_mod <-c("Peoria Ave", "Anthem Way".....)
```

That is I want to remove numbers and single characters from my vector of strings.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: You could fix your t-vector using Regular Expressions in R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html by calling the grep-function... removing single characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306312/regex-to-remove-single-characters-from-string ... removing numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363005/how-to-remove-numbers-from-a-string-with-regex

Comment: best not to use `t` as a variable name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tt <- c("8466 W Peoria Ave", "4250 W Anthem Way")
gsub(" [A-Za-z] ", "", gsub("[0-9]", "", tt))
[1] "Peoria Ave" "Anthem Way"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
# Data
t <- c("8466 W Peoria Ave", "4250 W Anthem Way")

# Remove numbers and split by whitespace
t.char <- sub("[[:alnum:]]* ", "", t) 
t.char.split <- strsplit(t.char, " ")

# Remove strings with only one character
t.mod <- sapply(t.char.split, function(i) {
  paste(i[which(nchar(i) > 1)], collapse = " ")
})

t.mod
[1] "Peoria Ave" "Anthem Way"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very good with regexs but I can take a stab, how about this:

```
t_mod <- gsub("^[0-9]{1,} [a-z][A-Z] ", "", t)
```

This will first strip any number of numerical digits at the start of the string, followed by a space, any alphabetic, and then another space. Then my t_mod looks like you needed:

```
t_mod
[1] "Peoria Ave" "Anthem Way"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char <- c("8466 W Peoria Ave", "4250 W Anthem Way")
gsub("[[:digit:]]+ *[[:alpha:]].","",char)
#[1] "Peoria Ave" "Anthem Way"
```